# Fatal error detected "Failed to execute script main".Works with pyinstaller, crash with HM NSIS

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I tried to execute a try except command on the app to get log of the error but it still crash so I think it is a problem of PATH ? library ?
Why does it work with pyinstaller and not after I created an installer.nsi with HM NSIS edit ?
I'm sorry but I have no idea of how to debug it !
It is a "simple" project. tkinter app, excel creation, 1 thread...
I don't know from where it comes from (I'm not good in system and OS).

PS: even stranger, when I install the app with Install.exe, if I decide to launch the app directly it works !!!
But it never work a second time when I use the shortcut or the .exe in C:\Program Files (x86)\MYDIRECTORY.

Answer (score 0):

This a permission problem, I tried to write on a protected file.

Solution to debug:
do not use --noconsole when you run pyinstaller, it will let you the console and with windows+G, you can keep track of the error even if the terminal stop immediatly after the crash of the programm.

(I tried to register the error in a .json in a try except but that the thing that made my program crash !)